# Java sort alphabetically, looks like it should work, but doesn't

Tags: java

I have this calculation in my bubble sort equation, but it doesn't seem to be working and I can figure out why.

This is in my Sort class.

```
System.out.println("\r" + "In order by title");
for (int out = 0; out < bookList.size(); out++) {
    for (int in = 0; in < bookList.size() - 1; in++) 
        if (bookList.get(in).getTitle().compareTo(bookList.get(in + 1).getTitle()) < 0) {
            Book temp = bookList.get(in);
            bookList.set(in, bookList.get(in+1));
            bookList.set(in+1, temp);        
        }    

        System.out.println(bookList.get(out).getTitle() + "   " + bookList.get(out).getRating());
}
}
```

The line...

```
 if (bookList.get(in).getTitle().compareTo(bookList.get(in + 1).getTitle()) < 0) {
```

is where I believe my problem lies. I can't seem to get my program to sort the list of book alphabetically. Anyone know a solution? The rest of my code is below.

Class: Book

```
public class Book {
String title;
int rating;

public Book(String pTitle, int pRating) {
    title = pTitle;
    rating = pRating;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public int getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setTitle(String newTitle) {
    title = newTitle;
}

public void setRating(int newRating) {
    rating = newRating;
}    
}
```

Class: Library

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Library {

public static void main (String [] args) {

    ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();

    Book b1 = new Book ("Huckleberry Finn", 5);
    Book b2 = new Book ("The Great Gadsby", 2);
    Book b3 = new Book ("Harry Potter", 3);
    Book b4 = new Book ("Animal Farm", 4);
    Book b5 = new Book ("The Mist", 1);
    bookList.add(b1);
    bookList.add(b2);
    bookList.add(b3);
    bookList.add(b4);
    bookList.add(b5);
    System.out.println("Original sequence");

    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < videoList.size(); cnt++) {
        System.out.println(bookList.get(cnt).getTitle() + "   " + bookList.get(cnt).getRating());

 Sort sortObject = new Sort();
 sortObject.calc(bookList);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Books. I want them sorted alphabetically. More specifically, an ArrayList.

Comment: Sorry, re-edited. I have an object in the main class that uses the calc function in my Sort class. It's printing, just not sorted.

Comment: Good, now we are getting somewhere. You'll want to find a good debugger and use it to see what happens in your `calc` method.

Comment: in your for loops you dont use the variable `out`. Try swapping `in+1` with out.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily sort a Collection by implementing Comparable and compareTo method and then use Collections.sort(arraylist);

Ex:

```
public class Book implements Comparable<Book>
{
   String title;
    ......

   public int compareTo(Book other)
   {
      return title.compareTo(other.title);
   }
}
```

Now you can sort your arraylist by: Collections.sort(bookList);

Comment: Is there any way I can edit the line I mentioned to make this work though? I thought that would work.

Comment: just implement comparable and compareTo method and it should work with your existing code.

Comment: Where do I put Collections.sort(bookList);

Comment: in main method Before you want to print it

Comment: Ok, but does that count as a "bubble sort" still?

Comment: what do you mean with bubble sort?

Comment: I'm trying to do a bubble sort exercise. Which is why I wanted my algorithm to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket after:

```
for (int in = 0; in < bookList.size() - 1; in++)
```

Also, if you are trying to print out the ordered list, you just misplaced this line:

```
System.out.println(bookList.get(out).getTitle() + "   " + bookList.get(out).getRating());
```

Your code should be something like this:

```
System.out.println("\r" + "In order by title");
for (int out = 0; out < bookList.size(); out++) {
    for (int in = 0; in < bookList.size() - 1; in++) {
        if (bookList.get(in).getTitle().compareTo(bookList.get(in + 1).getTitle()) < 0) {
            Book temp = bookList.get(in);
            bookList.set(in, bookList.get(in+1));
            bookList.set(in+1, temp);        
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Ordered list of books:");
for (int i = 0; out < bookList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(bookList.get(out).getTitle() + "   " + bookList.get(out).getRating());
}
```

Anyway, you should really learn how to implement and use Comparable. It will make your future life much easier.